# Need help appending a variable in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, append

When the `Add` button is pressed the price is taken from the second half of a 'split' line in the first list box. This is then multiplied by a value entered in a `textbox` or just entered as is into the second `listbox`.

I have then added a line below it in the second list box with the total price. When a new item is added the code removes the previous total price and replaces it with the new updated total price.

I'm looking to then append (add all the prices being listed in the second `listbox`) the prices together in the 'total price' section of the last line of the second list box.

Below is the code I have written so far.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string TheItem = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        string[] theSplits = TheItem.Split(' ');
        string FirstSplit = theSplits[0];
        string SecondSplit = theSplits[1];
        Decimal theNewTotal;
        Decimal theValue;



        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(TheItem);
            listBox2.Items.Add("Total Price:" + SecondSplit);
        }
        else
        {
            theValue = Convert.ToDecimal(SecondSplit) * Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text);
            listBox2.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + "x " + TheItem);
            theNewTotal = theValue;

            listBox2.Items.Add("Total Price:" + theNewTotal);               
        }
        if (listBox2.Items.Count > 2)
        {
            int theNumber = listBox2.Items.Count;
            listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(theNumber-3);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Maybe it would be good if you show a few 8textual) examples. Thus give an example with what is in listbox 1 and listbox 2 and after a click what you expect to be where (btw you mentioned a second listbox in the text but the code only uses 1 listbox?)

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? While removing?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off starting by removing the total price first, as you expend some effort trying to work around that. So something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   RemoveLastTotal();
   AppendPrices();
   AppendTotal();
}

private void RemoveLastTotal() {
   var lastItemIndex = listBox2.Items.Count-1;
   if (listBox2.Items[lastItemIndex].StartsWith("Total Price:"))
   {
       listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(lastItemIndex);
   }
}

private void AppendPrices() {
    string TheItem = Convert.ToString(listBox1.SelectedItem);
    string[] theSplits = TheItem.Split(' ');
    string itemDesc = theSplits[0];
    string itemPrice = theSplits[1];
    float quantity = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))? 0: float.Parse(textBox1.Text)

    if (quantity==0) {
       listBox2.Items.Add(TheItem);
    } else {
      var lineTotal = Convert.ToDecimal(itemPrice) * quantity;
      listBox2.Items.Add(textBox1.Text + " x " + TheItem + " = " + lineTotal);
   }        
}

private void AppendTotal()
{
    var total = 0;
    foreach(var item in listBox2.Items)
    {
      var splits = item.Split(' ');
      total += decimal.parse(splits[splits.length-1]);
    }
    listBox2.Items.Add("Total Price:" + total);               
}
```

That said, if you really want to do it "properly", you should separate the view i.e. the listbox from the model (`DataTable` for instance).